# Why is my Sql code not working in Derby in java?

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, derby

I am using eclipse and following http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-EclipseDbWebapps/index.html and it all works fine except when I try to run my own sql code.
Here it is:

```
CREATE TABLE honscores (
  idhonscores INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  Characters VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  Kills integer(11) NOT NULL,
  Deaths integer(11) NOT NULL,
  Assists integer(11) NOT NULL,
  XPM integer(11) NOT NULL,
  CK integer(11) NOT NULL);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the error message :

> Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line 5, column 20.
>
> Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 0 ms.

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: please edit your question to include the error message and with a little bit more details what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the error message, adding now

Comment: Ok I seem to have found the problem, I dont think the integers were meant to have the brackets with numbers and I had to tell it which schema to go into eg. 'app.honscores'

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you may want to post a complete answer to your question, then mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE app.honscores ( //schema name is before the table name
  idhonscores INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  Characters VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  Kills integer NOT NULL,
  Deaths integer NOT NULL,
  Assists integer NOT NULL,
  XPM integer NOT NULL,
  CK integer NOT NULL
);
```

Im pretty sure this is how I fixed it